# XPath - text from elements turned to lowercase

Tags: php, xpath

This Xpath/PHP code successfully checks to see if the text in any of the "name" elements in the XML file contain the string "Desk". Is there a way to turn the text retrieved from the "name" elements into all lowercase letters? (IE turn Desktop into desktop?).

Here is the XPath & PHP code:

```
$xmldoc = simplexml_load_file("products.xml");
$query = $xmldoc->xpath('/products/product[contains(name,"Desk")]');  
foreach($query as $Products) {
echo $Products->name . " ";
echo $Products->price . "<br>";
}
```

Here is the XML file (named product.xml):

```
<products>

<product type="Electronics">
<name>Desktop</name>
<price>499.99</price>
<store>Best Buy</store>
</product>

<product type="Hardware">
<name>Hand Saw</name>
<price>99.99</price>
<store>Lowes</store>
</product>

</products>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use  [strtolower](https://www.php.net/strtolower) ( string $str )

```
echo strtolower($Products->name) . " ";
echo strtolower($Products->price) . "<br>";
```

Comment: Thanks Nambi! But what is the Xpath code was:                                      $query = $xmldoc->xpath('/products/product[contains(name,"desk")]'); where the Xpath search string was "desk" (with a lower case d). Would there be a way to search and retrieve an XML element with the text "Desktop" (with a upper case D).